# Transloading is submitting the wrong form

Tags: transloadit

I have several forms on my page that all have the class "my_form".   I have activated transloadit as follows :

```js
 $(function() {
    $('.my_form').transloadit({
      wait: true,
        triggerUploadOnFileSelection: true
      });
   });
```

After the files upload and the form is submittted, the wrong form is submitted.  Transloadit is submitting the last form on the page with the class "my_form", rather than the specific form I submitted.

Any idea how this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transloadit can't know which form you mean if you have several that match the `my_form` class. One way to workaround this is to give one form the attrbute `id="upload_form"` and then refer to that as `$('#upload_form').transloadit(...etc`